# jquery fading in and out.

Tags: javascript, jquery, fadein, fadeout

Hi guys just doing some work with jquery and just got a question. I got an image inside a div and was wondering if with jquery i can make that image pop up on the screen by giving it an x and y coordinate. Then using this code i can make it move right

```
$('#red').pan({fps: 30, 
speed: 0.5, dir: 'right'});
```

And then make it fade out when it gets to a certain position on the screen.
Any help on this matter would be great as iam not to great with jquery atm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try someting like this:-

```
  $('#A').fadeOut( function() {
         $('#B').fadeIn();
       });
```

callback function can be taken by fadeout that runs after the first effect is completed

Comment: I guess i would use css to place the div were i want and then use that fade in function to make it appear on the screen? and then make it move to the left with my code, then i would use the fade out function to make it disappear?

Comment: Aright thanks. Will try that and if dosent work hopefully someone can help :).

Answer (score 1):

I would try something like this

```
function MoveAndFade(x, y)
{
    $('.box').fadeIn('slow', function ()
    {
        $(this).animate({ left: x, top: y }, 'slow', 'swing', function ()
        {
            $(this).fadeOut();
        });
    })    
}
```

Basically it will fade-in the div, then move it to the position you specify, then fade-out. This will happen sequentially.

You will want to change the selector `$('.box')` to the appropriate selector for your div. The current one selects the element with the class 'box'. You can then pass in any x or y value like: `MoveAndFade(50,100);`. You will also need to make sure the div has `position:absolute` css attribute.

You need to call the function `MoveAndFade` passing in the parameters that you want e.g.

```
<input type="button" value="Click me" onclick='MoveAndFade(150,50);' />
```

Or if you want to run when the DOM has loaded do something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.box').fadeIn('slow', function ()
    {
        $(this).animate({ left: '150', top: '50' }, 'slow', 'swing', function ()
        {
            $(this).fadeOut();
        });
    })    
});
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    MoveAndFade(150,50);
});
```

where `MoveAndFade()` is defined inside the `$(document).ready(function(){})` section.

Comment: Hi thanks for this code. It looks like it might work but iam new what am i suppose to change on this. Just the x and y right?

Comment: Ok. well i changed the .box to #laser. i changed left: x, top: y to left:'150px' which works fine. However the MoveAndFade(x, y) i changed it to what u wrote 50,100 but it wont work. Know why?

Comment: If u can give me an example with everything changed it would be great. Thanks again for all the help